# Google Script to Move Multiple Rows Simultaneously to Another Sheet - Archive Rows and Delete Completed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, move, delete-row

I'm trying to move multiple rows simultaneously from one Google sheet to another.

I would like to run the script once at the end of day to archive all the complete jobs.

The script I've put together will only move 2 rows at a time as long as the targeted cell is not blank. Ideally, it would continue to loop and only move the jobs marked 'Complete'.

The sheet I'm using is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jrsjag4LmHdmmDKTGrpm_sPiU9wODjUyaeOwOdm1SeQ/edit#gid=0)

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Admin')
      .addItem('Archive', 'archive')
      .addToUi();
}

function archive() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Scheduled");
  var range = sheet.getRange('A5:Q200');
  var sheetToMoveTheRowTo = "Archive";
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var row = sheet.getRange(5,1);

  for (var row = 5; row < numRows; row++) 
  {
    var status = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue(); 

      if ( status == "Complete") {

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(),1,1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Archive, Google Sheets, Move, Rows, Spreadsheet, Delete

You should set all the data to archive in one operation.  You can't delete all the rows in one operation, but you can save what rows to delete and then loop through the row numbers.

[Link to Publicly Shared Spreadsheet with Code](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jh7zl-1sAdaNECIa7WSKqGOW2In0BixS8xBksUNK_Do/edit?usp=sharing)

I'd set up the code to be structured like this:

```
function archive() {
  var arrayOfRowsToArchive,data,i,lastColumn,L,numRows,range,rowsToDelete,
      ss,sheet,sheetToMoveTheRowTo,startRow,status,targetSheet,thisRowsData;

  //USER INPUT:

  startRow = 5;

  //END OF USER INPUT

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Scheduled");
  sheetToMoveTheRowTo = "Archive";
  numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

  arrayOfRowsToArchive = [];
  rowsToDelete = [];

  data = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows - startRow, lastColumn).getValues();//Get all values except the header rows

  L = data.length;

  for (i=0; i < L; i++) {
    status = data[i][0];
    //Logger.log('status: ' + status);

    if ( status === "Complete") {
      thisRowsData = data[i];//Only get inner array of data
      //Logger.log('thisRowsData: ' + thisRowsData)
      arrayOfRowsToArchive.push(thisRowsData);//Push one row of data to outer array
      rowsToDelete.push(i+startRow);//Get the row number to delete later
    }
  }

  targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToMoveTheRowTo);
  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, arrayOfRowsToArchive.length, arrayOfRowsToArchive[0].length)
    .setValues(arrayOfRowsToArchive);

  //Logger.log('rowsToDelete: ' + rowsToDelete)

  for (i=rowsToDelete.length;i>0;i--) {//Delete from bottom up
    Logger.log((i-1).toString())
    Logger.log('rowsToDelete[i-1]: ' + rowsToDelete[i-1])
    sheet.deleteRow(rowsToDelete[i-1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: in addition to @Sandys script a Time-Based Trigger will set it of daily if you choose. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "return key."

Comment: thanks for the help.

had trouble finding out how to work the return key.

still having a problem - the script now deletes the header rows two at a time. 

After deleting the header rows, it moves the first two rows from the top when the  status in A5 is 'Complete'.

If the status in A5, is blank or 'In Progress' and the header rows are deleted, it gives the following error;

TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined

Comment: need to use shift and return in comments for a new line

Comment: I got it working.  I made a copy of your Sheet, and ran the code.  I'm getting all of the data all at once instead of getting each row one at a time.  And I needed to subtract 1 from `i` in the delete section because of the zero index.

Comment: nice one - it works now. Just one more question - does the for loop to delete rows need an if statement? The rows are getting moved okay,  but not been deleted from the original tab.

Comment: sheet.deleteRow(i), -1; ?

Comment: When I ran the updated code in the edited answer, it was deleting the correct row.  Take a look at the updated code in the edited answer.

Comment: Works great now. Thanks for all your help. Just had to change lastColumn -5 to numRows in data variable. I'll try the time based trigger too. Thanks.

Comment: Please up vote the **original question** so that it will be more likely to show up in a search.