# Why is this script archiving every line instead of the lines with the defined data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, move, delete-row

I want it to archive anything where the data under Completed By has information in it. Any help with defining the valuesToTestFor anything but blank would be appreciated as well.

Link to test document with script and a sorting script. incase you want to make a copy and see what it does when ran.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_7L26PvOZYKAeS9KfVsWi5nb9d08wLTYQkH5cDRvTOs/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the script Credit to Alan Wells for the original code from this link [Google Script to Move Multiple Rows Simultaneously to Another Sheet - Archive Rows and Delete Completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877432/google-script-to-move-multiple-rows-simultaneously-to-another-sheet-archive-ro/43877983#43877983?newreg=9dc741416bba4ec6abb4ee1bc8b7ffe8)

```js
function archive() {
  var arrayOfRowsToArchive,columnNumberOfValuesToTestFor,data,i,lastColumn,L,numberOfRowsToArchive,numRows,
      range,rowsToDelete,ss,sheet,sheetName,sheetToMoveTheRowTo,startRow,status,targetSheet,thisRowsData,
      valuesToTestFor;

  //USER INPUT:
  
  startRow = 2; //The row number to start from where the data starts - exclude header rows
  valuesToTestFor = "test";//Type one or more values to test for - If multiple values seperate by comma
  columnNumberOfValuesToTestFor = 9;
  sheetName = "Form Responses 1";//Name of sheet tab where the data will be removed from
  sheetToMoveTheRowTo = "Sheet7";
  
  //END OF USER INPUT
  
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);//Get the sheet tab with the data to be searched
  
  numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

  arrayOfRowsToArchive = [];
  rowsToDelete = [];

  //The getRange() method uses parameters of (start Row, start Column, Number of Rows to get, Number of Columns to get)
  data = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows - startRow, lastColumn).getValues();//Get all values except the header rows
  
  L = data.length;//Get the number of rows that are in the data
  
  for (i=0; i<L; i++) {//Loop through all the rows of data
    status = data[i][columnNumberOfValuesToTestFor];
    //Logger.log('status: ' + status);
    
    if (valuesToTestFor.indexOf(status) !== -1) {//Search for a match between the cell value and values to look for
      thisRowsData = data[i];//Only get inner array of data
      //Logger.log('thisRowsData: ' + thisRowsData)
      arrayOfRowsToArchive.push(thisRowsData);//Push one row of data to outer array
      rowsToDelete.push(i+startRow);//Get the row number to delete later
    }
  }

  if (arrayOfRowsToArchive) {
    numberOfRowsToArchive = arrayOfRowsToArchive.length;
    
    if (!numberOfRowsToArchive) {
      return;//No rows were found to archive
    }
  } else {//There is no good value for arrayOfRowsToArchive- There was an error
  
    Logger.log('There is a problem with arrayOfRowsToArchive');
  }
  
  targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToMoveTheRowTo);
  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, numberOfRowsToArchive, arrayOfRowsToArchive[0].length)
    .setValues(arrayOfRowsToArchive);

  //Logger.log('rowsToDelete: ' + rowsToDelete)
  
  for (i=rowsToDelete.length;i>0;i--) {//Delete from bottom up
    Logger.log((i-1).toString())
    Logger.log('rowsToDelete[i-1]: ' + rowsToDelete[i-1])
    sheet.deleteRow(rowsToDelete[i-1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your goal from your question. Can you provide your sample output situation you expect?

Comment: Try changing `if (valuesToTestFor.indexOf(status) !== -1)` into `if (valuesToTestFor)`. Besides, `if (arrayOfRowsToArchive)` would always give `true`, you should use `if (arrayOfRowsToArchive.length !== 0)`

Comment: @Tanaike i am trying to have it move any rows that have any information under the column completed by (so not blank) to the other sheet for archiving by pressing a button with the code bound to it.

Comment: @idfurw i changed the first line you listed on line 34 and the second on line 42. it seems to now still archive each row but leave the last row for no apparent reason. edits are on the same google sheet from original post if you wanna see it in action

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal using your sample Spreadsheet, you want to move rows 2-7 in "Form Responses 1" sheet to "Archive" sheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @tanaike yes this is correct. although the given form is an example of a much bigger document i am working with. so the goal is for the code to take any row with the "completed by column" filled in and move it to the Archive sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from `so the goal is for the code to take any row with the "completed by column" filled in and move it to the Archive sheet.`, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of it?